# Get byte representation of C++ class

Tags: c++, hash

I have objects that I need to hash with SHA256. The object has several fields as follows:

```
class Foo {
    // some methods
    protected:
       std::array<32,int> x;
       char y[32];
       long z;
}
```

Is there a way I can directly access the bytes representing the 3 member variables in memory as I would a struct ? These hashes need to be computed as quickly as possible so I want to avoid malloc'ing a new set of bytes and copying to a heap allocated array. Or is the answer to simply embed a struct within the class?

It is critical that I get the exact binary representation of these variables so that the SHA256 comes out exactly the same given that the 3 variables are equal (so I can't have any extra padding bytes etc included going into the hash function)

Comment: If you cast the address of the object to a `char*` you can inspect the entire object's byte representation

Comment: `struct` and `class` are almost the same keyword, so it's not clear what would work for one but not the other. You still have padding to deal with for structs. In addition, the maximum size (`sizeof(Foo)`) or the exact size (sum of sizes of each member represented) are known at compile-time, so it's unclear why a heap allocation would be needed.

Comment: Note that std::array<32, int> has its template arguments in wrong order.

Comment: this won't work in most cases. there will be padding between variables which are not visible in source code. Two equal objects will then have different hashes.

Comment: I could not find a reference on whether the standard imposes or not that for `std::array<T, n> x`, `&x` and `&x[0]` have same value. It is of course true for a plain array and false for a vector. I would bet a coin that it is true in most implementation but still wonder whether is is really *specified*.

Comment: @SergeBallesta AFAIK It has to be true, since `std::array` is standard layout and an aggregate.

Comment: Also the posted Foo is standard layout unless it has virtual functions among //some methods

Comment: [Here's what you want to do](https://godbolt.org/z/TP88cbY8a) but notice that even if I initialize all member variables, two default constructed `Foo`s do not get the same hash. That's due to the padding.@Raildex mentioned.

Comment: Embed a struct within the class. Composition is the way to go for this problem. Also, for such small class - even if you would have to copy it allocation is not necessary - it could easily fit on the stack.

Comment: @Xeverous How is that any different? To be sure, one would have to make sure that all padding bytes are always the same for all objects - or one takes the hash of each member and combine the hashes.

Comment: Crap - I actually forgot to initialize one of the member in my example - and if I do, it turns out that the example gives `true` for two default constructed objects. Fail :-) ... anyway... I can't be _sure_ that the hashes will be the same :-)

Comment: It seems all answers (my deleted answer included) overlooks the fact that _all_ member variables and their member variables _must not_ have _any_ padding for this to work

Comment: You are allowed to `reinterpret_cast<char *>` a pointer to anything, and `sizeof` will tell you when to stop. However as @TedLyngmo notes, if *any* subobject has even 1 padding bit, this will fail.

Comment: Padding, field alignment causes holes with in principle unitialized data. Ensure you zero the data, for instance by a compiler switch. I think it is not worth the resulting splintered solution.

Comment: @TedLyngmo One needs to do this recursively until no-padding members are reached. `intN_t` types have no padding bits, so these types are safe (it the implementation has no intN_t for N \in {8,16,32,64}, drop it like a hot potato; it has no business of running anything that computes SHA256). Arrays of no-padding types are no-padding. One can check if a `struct` is no-padding using the "magic tuple" technique. If it has padding, compute its hash member-wise.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, I was actually thinking about the magic tuple to do this. I'm thinking of undeleting my answer to go for a simpler - home made version with constraints. ... perhaps after dinner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Hash classes are able to take multiple regions before returning the hash, e.g. as in:

```
class Hash {
    public:
        void update(const void *data, size_t size) = 0;
        std::vector<uint8_t> digest() = 0;
}
```

So your hash method could look like this:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> Foo::hash(Hash *hash) const {
    hash->update(&x, sizeof(x));
    hash->update(&y, sizeof(y));
    hash->update(&z, sizeof(z));
    return hash->digest();
}
```

Comment: This does _not_ work if there is padding.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I was using wrappers over the openssl sha512 implementation that obscured this functionality.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Padding is skipped between the `update` calls. `sizeof` does not include padding.

Comment: @Fozi Yes, padding is included in `sizeof` -  I repeat - If _any_ sub object has padding - this breaks

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not for arrays, did you mean structs? Yes, but then you could do the same thing with the struct properties.

Comment: @Fozi Your method does not take into consideration what types you pass into it. Using this method on any object composed of different types, you _must_ make sure that your class does not introduce padding. You must also make sure that its members do not have padding. You must also make sure that the members members do not have padding etc etc...

Comment: @TedLyngmo The *only* members that can have padding are structs (`struct`, `class`, `union`, inB4 you language lawyer me). Everything else, including arrays and specifically `std::array` will work just fine.

Comment: Since I want to get in on the "this won't work in general case x" train: this won't work when the binary representation of the member variable is not representative of the object (things with dynamic memory allocation)

Comment: @Fozi Does `using strange_type = alignas(4) unsigned char;` have padding? Is `strange_type ` a `struct`?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Agree, but then those classes could have their own `hash` method. (And maybe the `hash` method should not call digest, only update.)

Comment: @Fozi I agree. I think Ted just wants to make the answers as complete as possible. To prevent future readers from agonizing over why this doesn't work for their problem. These situations are obvious to us, not necessarily everyone.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Indeed. I removed my own answer for the reason that the caveat would need to be so very very clear - much like your gigantic warning :-)

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yeah but his `alignas(4)` example is quite contrived IMHO. You got to stop somewhere or you overcomplicate things to a point where it is unintelligible.

Comment: @Fozi It's not. contrived. `alignas` is often used when hardware is involved. The point is that one _must_ have control of _every_ subobject down the chain for this to work.

Comment: I think everyone's made their points and everyone understands everyone else.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `using strange_type = alignas(4) unsigned char` is not legal C++. A type alias cannot have `alignas` applied to it. A variable or a class member can be declared `alignas` but then it does not affects its `sizeof`. A class type can be declared `alignas` but we deal with classes member-wise. An array type *cannot* be declared `alignas`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo So I just tried, `sizeof` still returns `1`. You are confusing padding in between properties and alignment. https://ideone.com/X4GpRG

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Darn `g++` .. it thinks that `typedef` is just dandy even with `-pedantic-errors`. `clang++` on the other hand confirms what you say.

Comment: @Fozi No I am not confusing the two. The point I was trying to make is that if you try to hash an object that has this kind of type in it, there will be padding - but the type I invented is illegal - so I'll drop that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I agree, but then you are supposed to call `update` on the properties of that object, and not just `update` the whole object, just as you would not simply `update(this, sizeof(*this))`.

Comment: @Fozi It would need to be a recursive call to all sub objects down to the last byte. With a _no-padding_ type trait of sorts where every type one uses must be cleared for use this way, yes, then it'd be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by making an iterator that knows the layout of your member variables. Make `Foo::begin()` and `Foo::end()` functions and you can even take advantage of range-based for loops.

If you can increment it and dereference it, you can use it any other place you're able to use a [LegacyForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator).

Add in comparison functions to get access to the common `it = X.begin(); it != X.end(); ++it` idiom.

Some downsides include: ugly library code, poor maintainability, and (in this current form) no regard for endianess.

The solution to the latter downside is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    friend class FooByteIter;

public:
    FooByteIter begin() const;

    FooByteIter end() const;

    Foo(const std::array<int, 2>& x, const char (&y)[2], long z)
    : x_{x}
    , y_{y[0], y[1]}
    , z_{z}
    {}

protected:
    std::array<int, 2> x_;
    char y_[2];
    long z_;
};

class FooByteIter {
public:
    FooByteIter(const Foo& foo)
        : ptr_{reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(foo.x_))}
        , x_end_{reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(foo.x_)) + sizeof(foo.x_)}
        , y_begin_{reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(foo.y_))}
        , y_end_{reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(foo.y_)) + sizeof(foo.y_)}
        , z_begin_{reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(foo.z_))}
    {}

    static FooByteIter end(const Foo& foo) {
        FooByteIter fbi{foo};
        fbi.ptr_ = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&foo.z_) + sizeof(foo.z_);

        return fbi;
    }

    bool operator==(const FooByteIter& other) const { return ptr_ == other.ptr_; }
    bool operator!=(const FooByteIter& other) const { return ! (*this == other); }

    FooByteIter& operator++() {
        ptr_++;
        if (ptr_ == x_end_) {
            ptr_ = y_begin_;
        }
        else if (ptr_ == y_end_) {
            ptr_ = z_begin_;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    FooByteIter operator++(int) {
        FooByteIter pre = *this;
        (*this)++;
        return pre;
    }

    char operator*() const {
        return *ptr_;
    }

private:
    const char* ptr_;

    const char* const x_end_;
    const char* const y_begin_;
    const char* const y_end_;
    const char* const z_begin_;
};

FooByteIter Foo::begin() const {
    return FooByteIter(*this);
}

FooByteIter Foo::end() const {
    return FooByteIter::end(*this);
}

template <typename InputIt>
char checksum(InputIt first, InputIt last) {
    char check = 0;
    while (first != last) {
        check += (*first);
        ++first;
    }

    return check;
}

int main() {
    Foo f{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, 5};
    for (const auto b : f) {
        std::cout << (int)b << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Checksum is: " << (int)checksum(f.begin(), f.end()) << std::endl;
}
```

You can generalize this further by making serialization functions for all data types you might care about, allowing serialization of classes that aren't plain-old-data types.

#### Warning

This code assumes that the underlying types being serialized have no internal padding, themselves. *This* answer works for *this* datatype because it is made of types which themselves do not pad. To make this work for datatypes that have datatypes that have padding, this method would need to be recursed all the way down.

Comment: I removed my answer because I overlooked the possibility that the member variables have padding. If any of them do, your solution will have the same problem as mine had. :-( It's not a problem for the class in the example though - but still.

Comment: Do you mean if any of the variables have "internal" padding? The serialization I normally do is generally for network transmission, and the way we handle it is recursive calls all the way down. For a variable type to be considered supported for the serialization, it needs to be either plain-old-data, or expose a tuple of its member variables. This is recursed at compile time. It's honestly a big template-y headache. I'd recommed boost archive if I understood how it worked.

Comment: Yes, if you have that control over the whole chain it should be fine. I think it would be wise to emphasize that in the answer. This method witll not work on types that one haven't made sure has no padding - all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast a pointer to object to a pointer to char. You can iterate through the bytes by increment. Use sizeof(foo) to check overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're able to make your class an [aggregate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), i.e. `std::is_aggregate_v<T> == true`, you can actually sort-of reflect the members of the structure.

This allows you to easily hash the members without actually having to name them. (also you don't have to remember updating your hash function every time you add a new member)

##### Step 1: Getting the number of members inside the aggregate

First we need to know how many members a given aggregate type has.
We can check this by (ab-)using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Example:
Given `struct Foo { int i; int j; };`:

```cpp
Foo a{}; // ok
Foo b{{}}; // ok
Foo c{{}, {}}; // ok
Foo d{{}, {}, {}}; // error: too many initializers for 'Foo'
```

We can use this to get the number of members inside the struct, by trying to add more initializers until we get an error:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept aggregate = std::is_aggregate_v<T>;

struct any_type {
    template<class T>
    operator T() {}
};

template<aggregate T>
consteval std::size_t count_members(auto ...members) {
    if constexpr (requires { T{ {members}... }; } == false)
        return sizeof...(members) - 1;
    else
        return count_members<T>(members..., any_type{});
}
```

Notice that i used `{members}...` instead of `members...`.
This is because of arrays - a structure like `struct Bar{int i[2];};` could be initialized with 2 elements, e.g. `Bar b{1, 2}`, so our function would have returned 2 for `Bar` if we had used `members...`.

##### Step 2: Extracting the members

Now that we know how many members our structure has, we can use [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to extract them.

Unfortunately there is no way in the current standard to create a structured binding expression with a variable amount of expressions, so we have to add a few extra lines of code for each additional member we want to support.

For this example i've only added a max of 4 members, but you can add as many as you like / need:

```cpp
template<aggregate T>
constexpr auto tie_struct(T const& data) {
    constexpr std::size_t fieldCount = count_members<T>();
    if constexpr(fieldCount == 0) {
        return std::tie();
    } else if constexpr (fieldCount == 1) {
        auto const& [m1] = data;
        return std::tie(m1);
    } else if constexpr (fieldCount == 2) {
        auto const& [m1, m2] = data;
        return std::tie(m1, m2);
    } else if constexpr (fieldCount == 3) {
        auto const& [m1, m2, m3] = data;
        return std::tie(m1, m2, m3);
    } else if constexpr (fieldCount == 4) {
        auto const& [m1, m2, m3, m4] = data;
        return std::tie(m1, m2, m3, m4);
    } else {
        static_assert(fieldCount!=fieldCount, "Too many fields for tie_struct! add more if statements!");
    }
}
```

The `fieldCount!=fieldCount` in the static_assert is intentional, this prevents the compiler from evaluating it prematurely (it only complains if the else case is actually hit)

Now we have a function that can give us references to each member of an arbitrary aggregate.

Example:

```cpp
struct Foo {int i; float j; std::string s; };

Foo f{1, 2, "miau"};
// tup is of type std::tuple<int const&, float const&, std::string const&>
auto tup = tie_struct(f);

// this will output "12miau"
std::cout << std::get<0>(tup) << std::get<1>(tup) << std::get<2>(tup) << std::endl;
```

##### Step 3: hashing the members

Now that we can convert any aggregate into a tuple of its members, hashing it shouldn't be a big problem.

You can basically hash the individual types like you want and then combine the individual hashes:

```cpp
// for merging two hash values
std::size_t hash_combine(std::size_t h1, std::size_t h2)
{
    return (h2 + 0x9e3779b9 + (h1<<6) + (h1>>2)) ^ h1;
}

// Handling primitives
template <class T, class = void>
struct is_std_hashable : std::false_type { };

template <class T>
struct is_std_hashable<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<std::hash<T>>()(std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type { };

template <class T>
concept std_hashable = is_std_hashable<T>::value; 

template<std_hashable T>
std::size_t hash(T value) {
    return std::hash<T>{}(value);
}

// Handling tuples
template<class... Members>
std::size_t hash(std::tuple<Members...> const& tuple) {
    return std::apply([](auto const&... members) {
        std::size_t result = 0;
        ((result = hash_combine(result, hash(members))), ...);
        return result;
    }, tuple);
}

template<class T, std::size_t I>
using Arr = T[I];

// Handling arrays
template<class T, std::size_t I>
std::size_t hash(Arr<T, I> const& arr) {
    std::size_t result = 0;
    for(T const& elem : arr) {
        std::size_t h = hash(elem);
        result = hash_combine(result, h);
    }
    return result;
};

// Handling structs
template<aggregate T>
std::size_t hash(T const& agg) {
    return hash(tie_struct(agg));
}
```

This allows you to hash basically any aggregate struct, even with arrays and nested structs:

```cpp
struct Foo{ int i; double d; std::string s; };
struct Bar { Foo k[10]; float f; };

std::cout << hash(Foo{1, 1.2f, "miau"}) << std::endl;
std::cout << hash(Bar{}) << std::endl;
```

[full example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TKo68rzhE)

##### Footnotes

- This only works with aggregates
- No need to worry about padding because we access the members directly.
- You have to add a few more `if`s into `tie_struct` if you need more than 4 members
- The provided `hash()` function doesn't handle all types - if you need e.g. `std::array`, `std::pair`, etc... you need to add overloads for those.
- It's a lot of boilerplate code, but it's insanely powerful.
- You can also use [Boost.PFR](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html) for the aggregate-to-tuple part, if you are allowed to use boost